# I cant get my simple shelve python script to work

Tags: python, shelve

Hey guys i am working on a project for school where i have to ask 10 math questions then store their score name and class but the only thing is i cant seem to get the right back to work in shelve. below is the code im trying to get to work any help would be good.

```
global username
global clss
global score
file = shelve.open('score.txt',writeback=True)
try:
    file['score'] = (username, score, clss)
finally:
    file.close ()
```

EDIT

The thing I am trying to do is to create a script that saves the score class and age of a person. the error im getting is that every time i run the script it deletes the previous data

EDIT change my code to

```
    global username
    global clss
    global score
    file = shelve.open('score',writeback=True)
    try:
        if 'scores' not in file.keys():
            file['score'] = [ (username, score, clss) ]
        else:
            file['score'].append( (username, score, clss) )
    finally:
        file.close ()
```

Comment: writeback is used to persist changes to mutable data structures.  You are storing a tuple here so writeback should not be applicable.  It would be helpful if you posted the rest of your file and what exactly the error you are facing is.

Comment: @jeff carey The error i am getting is that it is just re writing the whole file with a new lot of data instead of appending it to the old. I want add more data written in the same format.

Comment: I think I see what your issue is... see my updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above, writeback alone will not work if you are just using one tuple.  If you want to append a list of user/score/class (i.e. subject) tuples, then do that.  (Make sure to keep writeback set to true or else this direct call to append will not work).

```
try:
    if 'scores' not in file.keys():
        file['scores'] = [ (username, score, clss) ]
    else:
        file['scores'].append( (username, score, clss) )
```

Comment: i have changed all these things still same problem that it just re rights the file

Comment: i place this in my code but get a long error code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\Programs\python\lib\shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: 'score'

Comment: Be careful-- I renamed the saved variable to __scores__ to reflect that there are multiple of them

Answer (score 0):

Check the Python documentation for "open." https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

There is a second field, a string (e.g. "r+"), which changes whether the file is appended to, read-only, or re-written. That should help you.

You may want to bookmark the Python documentation online for more questions of this sort.

Comment: i appreciate what i think your saying that i should make the file open to append to but it still doesn't work with that

Comment: This is shelve.open() not the built-in open() for general file reading and writing.

Comment: Ah, thanks Jeff, you're right. I skimmed the question too quickly; serves me right.